# Spring boot Authentication Failure Handler - Custom with no additional url or query parameters

Tags: spring-boot, thymeleaf, forms-authentication

My current implementation of Spring Boot Login is as follows:

login.html:

```
<div class="error-message m-l-4" th:if="${errorMessage}" th:text="${errorMessage}"></div>
```

WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter - configure method:

```
formLogin().failureUrl("/login-error")
```

RequestMapper:

```
@RequestMapping("/")
public class Root {
    @GetMapping("login")
    public ModelAndView getLoginView(ModelMap mav) {    
        return new ModelAndView("login", mav);
    }
    
    @GetMapping("login-error")
    public RedirectView setErrorMessage(RedirectAttributes attributes) {
        attributes.addFlashAttribute("errorMessage", "Username or Password is invalid");
        return new RedirectView("login");
    }
}
```

The above is working perfectly when the user inputs invalid credentials the error is displayed on HTML. However, is there a way to accomplish the same result but get rid of the extra directory /login-error? I don't want it to be accessible despite redirecting to the login page with the error. I have tried to translate a custom AuthenticationFailureHandler (.failureHandler(new CustomAuthenticationFailureHandler())) to have the same effect but I can only return JSON not HTML. Basically, I want the exact same behavior as the Instagram Login Page.

See Pages in Order and upon Refresh back to the **exact** page as Page 1:
[image: Page 1]
[image: Page 2 - Press Login]
[image: Page 3 - Error Shown]
[image: Page 4 - Click Refresh]

Comment: My strong suit isn't java and I don't know what WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter does, but it should be possible to POST to the /login page, check the username and password and just return the ModelAndView of the login page with an extra attribute of "errorMessage". But again, I'm no expert at java.

Comment: @yvanavermaet The WebSecurityConfigureAdapter recognizes the fail attempt and on trigger Redirects to the specified URL. However as shown, in the mapping the GetRequest of \login (if I redirect to \login) is already occupied to display the login page normally (without the error message). I could use a Forward Request:  .failureForwardUrl(\login) (thus I will need a Post mapping). However, on Refresh of that page, it will attempt to send again a Post request instead of calling the Get Request mapping.